# How can I change Zoom options?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, zoom, photoshop-cs6

Since I started using photoshop I always zoomed by clicking and dragging, right to zoom in and left to zoom out.

Today with no explanation, the zoom tool switch to a box, which is incredibly impractical, if I want to zoom a little I have to do a huge motion, and it's a lot of additional clicks to zoom out.

I can't find any option about this, how do I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on what version of photoshop you are using but most of the zoom options can be changed in **General** preferences. Also adobe has some very useful information on their site: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/viewing-images.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't manage to get the "drag to zoom" option though. From the page you gave, what I want must be "scrubby zoom" but it's grayed out in the option bar, it says "OpenGL only". That must be the problem.

Comment: It's kind of another problem, but it literally stopped working after I rebooted my PC. I was working on a piece, I rebooted because my fan was going crazy, then when I reopened Photoshop, no OpenGL.